# How to clean up database with JdbcTemplate after all junit 5 tests are finished?

Tags: junit, jdbctemplate, spring-boot-test

I'm writting integration tests and I need to clean up database after one suite test (via @TestMethodOrder) is finished, either successfuly or with failure.

Obviously first thing come to mind was to use method with @AfterAll annotation, but it needs to be static. I'm using @Autowired JdbcTemplate, which cannot be static. Actually after few searches I found out, that no database connection should be static.

Is there any good solution for integration testing optionally with suits?